# Can App Verifier be used with Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, verification

I am writing a Windows Store App in C++ as a learning exercise.  I can't seem to get it to work with App Verifier however.  I follow the instructions on the verifier, run the app from the IDE and nothing happens.

I can't run the generated EXE manually because it needs to be run in an app container.

Can application verifier be used with store apps at all?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: Does it work in debug?

Comment: Of course.  Why would I ask if my application didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Windows Store App needs to be run in an app container which is process-isolated. Given this, I don’t think the application verifier could be used with Windows Store App.

Comment: you think, or you know?  The app cert kit runs it somehow, so why can't I?

Comment: It is just my understanding about it, so please feel free to tell me if I have any misunderstanding :)